# How to add multiple buttons with click functionality on each button in server side?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to dynamically generate link buttons from server side, all having click event handlers, but I am getting an error. How is it done properly? 
Thanks in advance!

Regards,
[image]

Comment: Please post your code as plain text and not as an image. If someone wants to test your code they have to type it over from screen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the arguments in `deleteBtn_click`

Is `EventArgs e` instead of `EventHandler e`